# Change ImageView background with a boolean

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView`. I want the background of this `ImageView` to be related on a boolean value.

boolean value is a static value that can change every where in my project but `ImageView` is just in a `GridView`.

That means when boolean value has been changed, the background of `ImageView` should be changed too.

Comment: you need to show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter (this is a sample)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView;

      if (convertView == null) {
         imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
         imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
         imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
      } 
      else 
      {
         imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }


      // Checking your boolean
     if (yourBoolean) {
           imageView.setImageResource(AAA);// AAA is your background image
     } else {
          imageView.setImageResource(BBB);// BBB is another your background image
     }

      return imageView;
   }
```

In your activity:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(this));
```

In your method that change Boolean variable:

```
gridView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />
</selector>
```

Comment: no this is not my point.for example you think I have a static boolean in a class General.myBoolean .I want to when I changed this boolean the background of my imageview automatically change.I think it is possible with selector but I dont know how